# :app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug FAILED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Hello I am trying to run an application react-native on a remote desktop

when I run ./gradlew clean it is build successfully. 
However I have an error when running ./gradlew assembleDebug

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe\CodePushResourcesMap-aab77707.json'
```

:app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug FAILED

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:recordFilesBeforeBundleCommandDebug'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 10 mins 1.501 secs
   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
  Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
  set up your Android development environment:
  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect to android folder and then use gradlew clean.
1.cd android
2.gradlew clean
I resolved this issues by using this comment